# Is there a way to lazy load a component within each mat-step?

Tags: angular, mat-stepper

I am trying to implement a mat-stepper which has different components within each step. I need to pass data from the firs step to the next so I am basically using @ViewChild and @Input to do that. But, I want the component in each step to be initialized only when the control is moved to that step and not in the very beginning. I tried using the component within  like how we would lazy load mat-tabs but it doesn't seem to work.Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 12):

For reference, there is a built-in way of lazy rendering `mat-step` that is described in [the Angular Material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview#lazy-rendering).

> If you have some content that you want to want to defer until the
> particular step is opened, you can put it inside an ng-template with
> the matStepContent attribute.

Here is an example:

```
<mat-vertical-stepper>
    <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Step 1</ng-template>
        <ng-template matStepContent>
            <p>This content was rendered lazily</p>
            <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-step>
<mat-vertical-stepper>
```

Comment: hi i tried this, now i have a problem with stepControl, i reference a component inside as [stepControl]="myComponent" and #myComponent, but with ng-template it does not exist yet `error TS2339: Property 'successForm' does not exist on type 'MintComponent'` is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 11):

You can use something like that

```
<mat-vertical-stepper #stepper>
   <mat-step #first_step>
      <ng-container *ngIf="stepper.selected == null || stepper.selected == first_step">
      </ng-container>
   </mat-step>
   <mat-step #second_step>
      <ng-container *ngIf="stepper.selected == second_step">
      </ng-container>
   </mat-step>
   <mat-step #third_step>
      <ng-container *ngIf="stepper.selected == third_step">
      </ng-container>
   </mat-step>
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

Note that the condition for the first step needs to include the check for null, too. Otherwise, you'll receive an ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError.

Edit

You could also make it like this

```
<mat-vertical-stepper #stepper>
       <mat-step>
          <ng-container *ngIf="stepper.selected === 0 ">
          </ng-container>
       </mat-step>
<mat-vertical-stepper/>
```

Of course, "0" is related to the first step.

Answer (score 0):

```
//In html file
<mat-vertical-stepper (selectionChange)="selectionChanged($event)">
    <mat-step #first_step>
        <ng-container *ngIf="stepNo == 0">
            //load component name here
        </ng-container>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
        <ng-container ngIf="stepNo == 1">
            //load component name here
        </ng-container>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
        <ng-container ngIf="stepNo == 2">
            //load component name here
        </ng-container>
    </mat-step>
</mat-vertical-stepper>

//In ts file
stepNo: number = 0;
selectionChanged2($event: StepperSelectionEvent) {
    console.log('$event.selectedIndex = ', $event.selectedIndex);
    this.stepNo = $event.selectedIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `stepper.selectedIndex`

```html
<mat-vertical-stepper #stepper>
    <!-- Step 1 -->
    <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Step 1</ng-template>
        <ng-template matStepContent>
          <ng-container *ngIf="stepper.selectedIndex === 0">
            <p>This content was rendered lazily</p>
            <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
           </ng-container>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-step>
       <!-- Step 2 -->
    <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Step 2</ng-template>
        <ng-template matStepContent> 
           <ng-container *ngIf="stepper.selectedIndex === 1">
             <p>This content was rendered lazily - content 2</p>
             <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next 2</button>
           </ng-container>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-step>
<mat-vertical-stepper>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ngx-mat-step-lazy-load` third party package

> You can find from here [ngx-mat-step-lazy-load](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-step-lazy-load)